# How can I assign a Purity III template to an alias

Tags: templates, multilingual

So in Joomla you may choose what kind of menu item you make, e.g. to an article or a 'system link' like this. On a multilingual site, I have in the mainmenu a button that links to an alias. The problem is, that the default template, Purity III, is assigned to this menulink, whatever I try to do. So I end up having the menu of one of the languages (that of the default assigned Purity template) on the page of whatever menu-alias I make.

In the Purity III template, you have to assign which menu you want to show, so with multi-language sites each language should have it's own template.

About the alias:
The alias is an alias to a hidden menu-item. In order to show a loginpage when a user is not logged in this menu-item's access is limited to registered.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't assign it to the hidden menu item? An alias by nature isn't real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add another copy of the Purity III template as default template. In this Purity III assign another hidden menu with aliases to all the menu items with their assigned languages. Lots of overkill, but the only way to solve this configuration problem I think.